# finding columnspace for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

For the matrix above, can we find the column space even we do not have the original matrix before performing Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The column space is in $\mathbb R^3$, and it is all of $\mathbb R^3$ because the first three columns of that matrix are the standard basis for $\mathbb R^3$ and therefore span $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Can I know when I need to refer back to the original matrix and when I don't need?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question.  [Gaussian elimination](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852464/why-gaussian-elimination-on-the-columns-changes-the-column-space) could [change](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376284/do-row-operations-change-the-column-space-of-a-matrix) the column space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your particular matrix, the rank is $3$. Since the column length is $3$, the column space must be $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In general, we do need the original matrix but this is a special case.

Comment: So can I say that when the matrix is full rank, I can directly find the column space without referring back to the original matrix?

Comment: @newbie You can if the matrix is at least as wide as it is tall.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Look at the first three columns. They are the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^3$.